# How to call Microsoft Graph API "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/" in node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I had created azure OAuth connection settings in azure active directory, and I used azure graph API "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/" to get the user details.

I called this API in postman and pass the user token in Authorization and I get all the user details. The below response which I get from the postman when I call this "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/" API.

Eg.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "raman",
    "givenName": "kuamr",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "sdf-890b52347751",
    "userPrincipalName":
"kumar_google.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "dsfc-29c6827f2fbe"
}
```

But now I need to call this API in node.js. How to call this API in node.js and how to get the response which I get in postman.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node) that you can follow.

It uses [microsoft-graph-client](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) for making calls to Microsoft Graph.

[passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) for authenticating and getting access tokens and [simple-oauth2](https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2) for token management.

Here is the relevant code to make call to the enpoint with access token (in step 3), but it will be good for you to go through the detailed steps to understand the full flow.

```
var graph = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');

module.exports = {
  getUserDetails: async function(accessToken) {
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);

    const user = await client.api('/me').get();
    return user;
  }
};

function getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken) {
  // Initialize Graph client
  const client = graph.Client.init({
    // Use the provided access token to authenticate
    // requests
    authProvider: (done) => {
      done(null, accessToken);
    }
  });

  return client;
}
```